# Django query filter, passing a date results in an invalid SQL syntax

Tags: python, django

```
z = Pokes.objects.filter(
    pokestiming__when_start__lte=datetime.now(), 
    pokestiming__when_end__gte=datetime.now(),
    pokestiming__next_poke__lte=datetime.now(),
    poke_deleted=0,
    poke_operating=1,
)
```

That's a query I'm using. It selects any Poke object, with a PokesTiming object (foreign key) within the date ranges. It's basically a start date and expiry date.

Problem is, passing datetime.now(), and even though it seems to be the exact same syntax in the django docs, the SQL result is:

> SELECT [fieldnames] FROM `pokes` INNER JOIN `pokes_timing` ON (`pokes`.`id` = `pokes_timing`.`poke_id`) WHERE (`pokes`.`poke_deleted` = 0 AND `pokes_timing`.`when_start` <= 2010-02-01 00:00:00 AND `pokes_timing`.`next_poke` <= 2010-02-01 13:50:48 AND `pokes_timing`.`when_end` >= 2010-02-01 13:50:48 AND `pokes`.`poke_operating` = 1 ) LIMIT 21

That is, the dates passed are just dates, not wrapped in string quotes, which results in an error and no results. That query ^ was retrieved by [this method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

I'm sure I'm missing something silly

---

Models:

```
class Pokes(models.Model):
    poke_title = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    poke_text = models.TextField()
    poke_email = models.CharField(max_length=450)
    poke_email_verified = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    poke_key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    poke_operating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    poke_deleted = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'pokes'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.poke_title

class PokesTiming(models.Model):
    poke = models.ForeignKey(Pokes)
    interval_min = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=30)
    interval_max = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=120)
    when_start = models.DateTimeField()
    when_end = models.DateTimeField()
    last_run = models.DateTimeField()
    is_single = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    next_poke = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'pokes_timing'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.poke
```

---

Bah - Must have just been me. It seems to work through Django now (the test data I have must have been wrong - it returns a result now) but the raw SQL query doesn't work. I guess Django does something to it before it's executed? Either way it seems to be working.

Comment: db.connection.queries shows me the same thing, but it works just fine (running the query does return the correct results). what db engine are you using, and what error are you getting when you run the query?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, and it returns the following:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND pokes_timing ...`. It works if the datetime part is quoted, but if I just pass datetime.now(), it doesn't add the quotes.

Comment: Can you show the model definitions for `PokesTiming` and `Pokes`?

Comment: I find it strange that you call datetime.now() 3 times, but get different results (look in the query - one of the times is 00:00:00 and the other 2 are not). maybe you should assign the results of datetime.now() to some variable and pass that to the filters?

Comment: That would have been when I attempted to use datetime.now().date() instead, just to see if it worked. I also added a response below.

Comment: I wonder why it shows "LIMIT 21". You did not specify a limit anywhere. I am doing a similar query now. In the SQL log it shows the query twice, 1st time with the "LIMIT 21", 2nd time without.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Potential Django Bug In QuerySet.query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926483/potential-django-bug-in-queryset-query)

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug report for this issue that was closed as invalid because there is no existing way for Django to get the actual query sent to the database.

[#17612 - SQLite, filter, datefield, datetime no quotes around date in sql query](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17612)

You can see that this limitation has been mentioned in the official documentation at this point.

[Databases - Parameters not quoted in connection.queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#parameters-not-quoted-in-connection-queries)

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution (from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741):

```
import datetime
from django.db import connection
from myapp.models import Entry
today_entry_list = Entry.objects.filter(post_date=datetime.date.today())
sql, params = today_entry_list.query.sql_with_params()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('EXPLAIN ' + sql, params)
print(cursor.db.ops.last_executed_query(cursor, sql, params)[8:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Django will always cast all field to the proper SQL syntaxe, which you probably don't when you do it manually. Hence your error.