# Django getting executable raw sql for a QuerySet

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I know that you can get the SQL of a given QuerySet using

```
print query.query
```

but as we know from a previous question ( [Potential Django Bug In QuerySet.query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926483/potential-django-bug-in-queryset-query) ) the returned SQL is not properly quoted. See http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/query.py

Is there any way that is it possible to get the raw, executable SQL (quoted) for a given QuerySet without actually executing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django never creates the raw sql, so no. To prevent SQL injection, django passes the parameters separately to the database drivers at the last step. The best way to get the actual SQL is to look at your query log, which you cannot do before you execute the query.

Comment: +1. @epoch: Correct, the answer is no. If you are curious to see the query as it passed to the backend, you can use the following snippet. `from django.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS; queryset.query.get_compiler(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).as_sql()`

Comment: I don't really see the problem with `__str__` when querying a PostgreSQL database when doing `Something.objects.all().query`?

Comment: But there is a problem when querying a development database (sqlite).

Comment: Is it safe to use queryset.query.get_compiler(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).as_sql() as arguments to the cursor.execute (from django cursor) ? Please review my question and edit 4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726004/django-queryset-vs-raw-query-performance