# Django Queryset Filter Missing Quotes

Tags: python, django

I have a list and I want to filter my Queryset when any of these items is found in a foreign table's non-primary key 'test'. So I write something like this:

```
test_list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
return cls.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [models.Q(next_task__test = item) for item in test_list]))[:20]
```

This returns an empty list. When I look at the SQL query it generated, I get:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE "job"."next_task_id" IN (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5) LIMIT 20;
```

Whereas what it should have been is this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE "job"."next_task_id" IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5') LIMIT 20;
```

Without the quotes, SQLite3 believes those are column names, and does not return anything. When I manually add the quotes and execute an SQLite3 query on the table without Django at all, I get the desired results. How do I make Django issue the query correctly?

Comment: why don't you use: `cls.objects.filter(next_task__test__in=test_list)` ?

Comment: Putting `in` changes nothing. Putting `exact` makes a chain of `OR`s, but the missing quotes are still missing. Typecasting as str has no effect.

Comment: Yeah, don't trust `QuerySet.query`'s generated string. The query is parametrized, so there is, in fact, no string that represents the populated SQL of what's being executed. I'm sure that the issue is something else in the query that's causing zero results.

Comment: @keyser add str(item) works, I think Q think its not string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Potential Django Bug In QuerySet.query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926483/potential-django-bug-in-queryset-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is quite interesting, it seems to happen with SQLite only. It's known here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14091 and in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#sqlite-connection-queries).

So basically the query might not be wrong, but when you get the query back with Django it looks wrong:

```
>>> test_list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
>>> cls.objects.filter(next_task__test__in=test_list).query.__str__()

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE "job"."next_task_id" IN (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);
```

Work around: if you really think the query is wrong, then provide more quote for the list, something like:

```
>>> test_list = ["'test1'", "'test2'", "'test3'", "'test4'", "'test5'"]
>>> cls.objects.filter(next_task__test__in=test_list).query.__str__()

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE "job"."next_task_id" IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');
```

I would rely on the standard one anyway, the work around above is too hackish.

Comment: The doc says the query may not print correctly to the console, which is fine, but Django is returning en empty list with this query, and when I add the quotes and run it in SQLite3 manually, I get the result I want. So the query is not only being printed wrong, it is also being run wrong somehow.

Comment: So if you add more quotes to the `test_list` like in my work around above, does it work? I still think this issue is something else.

Comment: 1) the same error for PSQL 2) this solution won't work for, say, "icontains".

Answer (score 1):

I really like the answer from @Andrey-St, but a colleague pointed out that this makes a round trip to the database to do the work.  So instead, we changed it to just grab the formatted query from the cursor.

```
 def stringify_queryset(qs):
     sql, params = qs.query.sql_with_params()
     with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         return cursor.mogrify(sql, params)
```

(We're using psycopg2 for Postgres -- I am not sure if `mogrify()` is available on other DB engines).

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringify_queryset(qs: QuerySet) -> str:
    sql, params = qs.query.sql_with_params()
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('EXPLAIN ' + sql, params)
        raw_sql =  cursor.db.ops.last_executed_query(cursor, sql, params)
    raw_sql = raw_sql[len('EXPLAIN '):]
    return raw_sql
```

(taken from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741)