Django ORM to query string treats model choice value as column
I have the following Django ORM code and something weird is happening.
When I comment the if part for library_level, query is working fine. If I add any new Q expression then the value provided as Q(field=value), value is treated as another field.
query = (
        (Q(domains=[]) | Q(domains__contains=domain))  # rule matches domain
        & (Q(klass=[]) | Q(klass__contains=dom_class))  # rule matches class
        & (Q(standards__contains=cdisc_version))  # rule matches standards
        & (~Q(exclusions__contains=domain))  # domain is not in excluded list
        & (~Q(exclusions__contains=dom_class))  # dom_class is not in excluded list
    )

    if not library_level:
        query &= ~Q(rule_type=DataCheckRuleType.DATASET_CHECK)

    required_checks = DataCheckRule.objects.filter(query).values(
        "rule_id",
        "domains",
        "message",
        "description",
        "exclusions",
        "klass",
        "standards",
        "detail_string",
        "ex_domains",
        "rule_type",
        "params",
    )
    sql_query = str(required_checks.query)

Printing above sql_query gives
SELECT "datacheck_rules"."rule_id", "datacheck_rules"."domains", "datacheck_rules"."message", "datacheck_rules"."description", "datacheck_rules"."exclusions", "datacheck_rules"."klass", "datacheck_rules"."standards", "datacheck_rules"."detail_string", "datacheck_rules"."ex_domains", "datacheck_rules"."rule_type", "datacheck_rules"."params" FROM "datacheck_rules" WHERE (("datacheck_rules"."domains" = \'[]\' OR "datacheck_rules"."domains" @> \'"DATA"\') AND ("datacheck_rules"."klass" = \'[]\' OR "datacheck_rules"."klass" @> \'"UNKNOWN"\') AND "datacheck_rules"."standards" @> \'"SDTMIG 3.2"\' AND NOT ("datacheck_rules"."exclusions" @> \'"DATA"\') AND NOT ("datacheck_rules"."exclusions" @> \'"UNKNOWN"\') AND NOT ("datacheck_rules"."rule_type" = dataset_check))

You can see that 'dataset_check' is treated as column instead of string which is giving me an error, mentioned column don't exist.
I am creating sql_query to use as
relevant_checks = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connections["default"])


My DataCheckRuleType is as
class DataCheckRuleType(models.Choices):
    DATASET_CHECK = "dataset_check"

My Model is
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    rule_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=DataCheckRuleType.choices)


class DataCheckRule(BaseModel):
    domains = models.JSONField(default=list)
    exclusions = models.JSONField(default=list)
    klass = models.JSONField(default=list)
    standards = models.JSONField(default=list)
    ex_domains = models.JSONField(default=list)

The values, you see on ORM filter comes through API payload.
I think my code is fine and commenting if also gives result, Do anyone knows what am I missing here?

Can you share the model? domains=[] does not seem to make much sense

Furthermore what exactly do you want to filter?

I have added the model. You can see the code that filter is little complex but we can clearly see that I am trying to fetch particular rules based on payload,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078542/django-queryset-filter-missing-quotes

@Yubraj which database are using?

Show us the complete error traceback for your error instead of saying "XYZ is giving me an error". Printing the SQL using the query attribute is not a reliable way of debugging, the parameters are sent separately to the database and the query attribute just interpolates them to display them to you as a string.

I am using postgres @Tanveer

While not really the error, I would strongly advise not to use JSON blobs for collections (i.e. non-atomic fields): https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/non-atomic-jsonfield-s.html
