# Django queryset.query and query run in mysql console doesn't give the same result

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I have 2 Models: Project and ProjectTweet.

Project has a relation OneToMany with ProjectTweet (related name: "tweets")

Here is my queryset:

```
current_pledge = 1000000
projects = Project.objects.filter(state = "live").filter(pledged__gt=current_pledge).exclude(tweets__step__gte=current_pledge)
```

And here the result of

```
print projects.query


SELECT `ks_project`.* FROM `ks_project` WHERE (`ks_project`.`state` = live AND `ks_project`.`pledged` > 1000000.0 AND NOT (`ks_project`.`id` IN (SELECT U1.`project_id` AS Col1 FROM `ks_projecttweet` U1 WHERE U1.`step` >= 1000000)))
```

(i've replaced the long field list by `ks_project`.* only for post readability)

This query evaluted in django give me 0 result, but i should have one.

And indeed when i copy the query in mysql console (same user) i get my unique result... (just adding quote to string, since they are added only when evaluting query like it's said in: [Potential Django Bug In QuerySet.query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926483/potential-django-bug-in-queryset-query))

Any idea on what is causing this difference?

Comment: i've tested it without the first filter (state = "live) and it still give me 0 result (and more than one, as expected in mysql console). Here is the request (a bit simpler than previous one) `SELECT `ks_project`.* FROM `ks_project` WHERE (`ks_project`.`pledged` > 1000000.0 AND NOT (`ks_project`.`id` IN (SELECT U1.`project_id` AS Col1 FROM `ks_projecttweet` U1 WHERE U1.`step` >= 1000000)))`

Comment: The simplest explanation is that Django is using a different copy of the database than the one you're accessing in the console. Is that a possibility?

Comment: No i'm using the one created by django ORM :/, i guess it may have something to do with an intermediate operation done just before evaluating the query (the same that quote strings). But even if in this case i see an other option (make two queries and difference between result instead of using "exclude" method), i'd like to rely on queryset.query to debug my queries...

Comment: What is U1 in the query ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how i could miss that but my "step" field that i compare using `.exclude(tweets__step__gte=current_pledge)`

is a CharField instead of FloatField... i've change that and now the query in mysql console and queryset give me same result. However i would have liked  an error instead of giving me 0 result

> cannot use gte with a charfield

or something like that.